# SVN + SASL users privilege separation

Tags: svn, sasl

I have and SVN + SASL server which works fine, but on this servers are multiple repositories and multiple SASL accounts. IS there a way to specify which users to access a specific repository like when specifying users in the passwd file ?

Comment: What method are you using to serve them - svnserve, I assume?  Different listeners for each repo, or a single one?

Comment: yes i,m using svn protocol and single listener on default port
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Since each SVN repo use a different realm privileges to specific repositories can be assigned based on the realm username@realm.